# How to return a value from my AWS Lambda so that the Queue Triggering the Lambda will retry Lambda Execution?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS Queue triggering my AWS Lambda. There are situations when I want to provide a response from the Lamba without raising an Exception. I tried returning a None but, the queue is not triggering the Lambda again.

Here is my Lamda getting triggered by the queue

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        do_something()
    except:
        return None
```

When I raise an exception here, the Lamda is getting retried again. But then, I don't want to raise an exception here for my Lambda to get triggered again. How can I achieve this? I tried sending the following instead of None.

```
{
    'statusCode': 500
}
```

That also doesn't get my Lambda to get triggered again.

Comment: Where do you want the return message from the Lambda to go to?

Comment: This is how the AWS Lambda SQS integration works. It retries on exception. If you want it to retry you need to throw an exception. This isn't a web service, so trying to return HTTP status codes isn't going to accomplish anything.